# Google App Engine Python: Class Definition "Invalid Syntax"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, syntax-error

When I run this code in the dev_appserver it gives me the "Invalid syntax" error at line 22, where the HugAPanda class is initialized. Does anybody know why this would happen? Here's the code:

```
import wsgiref.handlers
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class PandasHugs(db.Model):
  message = db.IntegerProperty()

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ListOfHugs = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM PandasHugs")
        Adder = 0
        for PandasHugs in ListOfHugs:
            Adder = Adder + 1
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<h6>Panda has ' + str(Adder) + ' hugs!</h6>')
        self.response.out.write("<form action=\"/HugPanda\" method=\"post\"><div><input type=\"text\" name=\"PandaMessage\" value=\"A message for a panda.\"></div><div><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Hug a panda?\"></div></form></body></html>">


class HugAPanda(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        HugForAPanda = PandaHugs()
        HugForAPanda.message = self.request.get('PandaMessage')
        HugForAPanda.put()
        self.redirect('/main')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
  [('/', MainPage), ('/main', MainPage), ('/HugPanda', HugAPanda)],
  debug=True)

def main():
  run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Thanks again!
-Neil

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, I believe this is a perfectly acceptable, albeit easily solved, question for someone more familiar with python and programming in general.  ie.  Noobs ARE allowed here. This IS one of the more confusing error messages one can get in Python.

Comment: This might be unrelated to the question itself, but you have message = db.IntegerProperty(), and then do a HugForAPanda.message = self.request.get('PandaMessage'), which is a string. I haven't tried to run this, but it seems that the put() should fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have invalid syntax in a line above. (Line 15 it looks like)

```
self.response.out.write("<form action=\"/HugPanda\" method=\"post\"><div><input type=\"text\" name=\"PandaMessage\" value=\"A message for a panda.\"></div><div><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Hug a panda?\"></div></form></body></html>">
```

Extra '>' at the end should be replace with ')'.

This is a very good reason to follow python convention and limit line length to 79 characters.  I won't argue with going up to 120 if that is standard at your organization, but it certainly should not be written the way it's presented here :)

In this case I'd recommend writing readable html code (ie. properly indented) in triple quotes.  In your case I would use single triple quotes so you do not have to escape every ".  I just recommend the single quotes here to avoid confusion, but I believe """ will also work in this case.

ie.

```
self.response.out.write('''<html>
  <body>
    <h6>Panda has %s hugs!</h6>
      <form action="/HugPanda" method="post">
        <div>
          <input type="text" name="PandaMessage" value=
          "A message for a panda.">
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Hug a panda?">
        </div>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>''' % Adder)
```

Just noticed some errors in the html after rewriting your code should have '/>' to close your input tags.  Good style can go a long way in avoiding errors without the use of any tools!

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Using a templating system would be 99.9% better than using triple quotes, too.

Comment: That is a great suggestion for something of any significant scope, complexity, or longevity.  There are several templating systems available for python and it will take a (usually small) bit of time to learn the one you choose to use.

Answer (score 2):

The end of your line

```
self.response.out.write("<form....da?\"></div></form></body></html>">
```

should be replaced with.

```
self.response.out.write("<form....da?\"></div></form></body></html>")
```

Parenthesis are unbalanced. Also, although that's not syntactically wrong, but you need to reconsider the indentation to 4-spaces uniformly in whole file.

Happy Coding.